# Flood fill algorithm stackoverflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flood-fill

Im working on a painting game but i can't get the flood fill algorithm to work on large areas. Its a recursive algorithm and i read that implementing a stack might work however i can get it to work as well. Here's the code;

```
    private void FillCluster(int x, int y, int colorIndex, HashSet<string> traversedCells)
        {
            Debug.Log(colorIndex);
            // Check if this cell is within the bounds of the picture and has a color number and the
            if(x < 0 || x >= ActivePictureInfo.XCells ||
                y < 0 || y >= ActivePictureInfo.YCells ||
                ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] == -1 ||
                ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] != colorIndex)
            {
                return;
            }

            string cellKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}", x, y);

            // Check if this cell has already been traversed by FillBlob
            if (traversedCells.Contains(cellKey))
            {
                return;
            }
            
            // Check if this cell is already colored in with the correct color
            if (!ActivePictureInfo.HasProgress || ActivePictureInfo.Progress[y][x] != -1)
            {
                ColorCell(x, y, colorIndex);
            }
            
            // Add this cells key to the traversed hashset to indicate it has been processed
            traversedCells.Add(cellKey);
            
            // Recursively call recursively with the four cells adjacent to this cell
            FillCluster(x - 1, y, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x + 1, y, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x, y - 1, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x, y + 1, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x - 1, y - 1, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x - 1, y + 1, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x + 1, y - 1, colorIndex, traversedCells);
            FillCluster(x + 1, y + 1, colorIndex, traversedCells);
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: This question lacks a description of the problem...

Comment: @jeekii StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar im trying to change the recursive algorithm to iterative. Flood fill algorithm doesn't work for high pixel pictures and gives a stackoverflow error.

Comment: You could queue parameters and not use recursion but while queue has items process parameters and add next options if not already done eventually it will have no pixels left to do and routine will end

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you are getting a stackOverflow is because the state of the previous iteration is saved on the stack unless both of these condition are met:

- You are doing tail recursion (look it up, but it isn't relevant right now)
- Your language optimizes tail recursion (C# doesn't)

As the stack size is limited and your algorithm very quickly reaches thousands of calls one after the other, you cannot make the recursive version work in C#, that is impossible, but it seems like you understood this already

Here is a pseudocode solution to do it without recursion. *I don't know C# so the synthax is not correct, but the idea is correct, you will have to transform it into proper C#*

```
private void FillCluster(int x, int y, int colorIndex, HashSet<string> traversedCells) {
    Debug.Log(colorIndex);
    // Check if this cell is within the bounds of the picture and has a color number and the
    
    //Declare a set, add inside the current node
    Set<Tuple> nodesToFill = new Set<>()
    nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x, y));
    //Replace the recursion by a loop
    for (Tuple tuple in nodesToFill) {
        //initialize the current position
        x = tuple.first
        y = tuple.second
        //Deal with the current node
        if(FillClusterInner(x, y, colorIndex, traversedCells)) {
        //Add the new nodes to the set instead of using recursion
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x-1, y))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x + 1, y))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x, y - 1))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x, y + 1))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x - 1, y - 1))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x - 1, y + 1))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x + 1, y - 1))
            nodesToFill.add(new Tuple(x + 1, y + 1))
        }
        //Remove the current tuple from the set as you have dealt with it
        nodesToFill.remove(tuple)
    }
}

//This is a non-recursive method which fills a single specified node
bool FillClusterInner(int x, int y, int colorIndex, HashSet<string> traversedCells) {
    if(x < 0 || x >= ActivePictureInfo.XCells ||
            y < 0 || y >= ActivePictureInfo.YCells ||
            ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] == -1 ||
            ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] != colorIndex)
    {
        return false;
    }
        
    string cellKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}", x, y);

    // Check if this cell has already been traversed by FillBlob
    if (traversedCells.Contains(cellKey))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Check if this cell is already colored in with the correct color
    if (!ActivePictureInfo.HasProgress || ActivePictureInfo.Progress[y][x] != -1)
    {
        ColorCell(x, y, colorIndex);
    }
    
    // Add this cells key to the traversed hashset to indicate it has been processed
    traversedCells.Add(cellKey);
    return true;
}
```

You can see the idea: instead of recursion, we use a set, which contains all the indexes of the nodes we have yet to fill. You add to this set instead of calling the recursive function, and you remove from the set each position you have handled. When the set is empty you have filled every cell that had to be filled.

Comment: `HashSet<long>` and `x << 32 | y` would be more efficient. Also i think it misses a break condition

Comment: It doesn't miss a break. The loop will exit when the hash is empty. As for the implementation details I'm not a C# dev so I don't know these details

Comment: but it was missing a check and adding the nodes no matter what (which could have been a "continue" I guess)  so yeah that was bugged. In addition you are correct in your answer that the travesedCells set is useless.

Comment: My comment was made before the edit and you fixed it. The code looks quite good however in c# you cant iterate and change a collection at the same time (Exception) so it has to be a while loop with count check and .First() inside.

Answer (score 0):

a version without having to remember all visited cells because they are already marked by the color

```
    private void FillCluster(int x, int y, int colorIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log(colorIndex);

        var currentSeam = new Queue<PointDirection>();
        if (FillPoint(x, y, colorIndex))
        {
            currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x - 1, y, Direction.Left));
            currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x + 1, y, Direction.Right));
            currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x, y - 1, Direction.Up));
            currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x, y + 1, Direction.Down));
        }
        while (currentSeam.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = currentSeam.Dequeue();
            if (FillPoint(current.X, current.Y, colorIndex))
            {
                if (current.Direction != Direction.Right)
                    currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x - 1, y, Direction.Left));
                if (current.Direction != Direction.Left)
                    currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x + 1, y, Direction.Right));
                if (current.Direction != Direction.Down)
                    currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x, y - 1, Direction.Up));
                if (current.Direction != Direction.Up)
                    currentSeam.Enqueue(new PointDirection(x, y + 1, Direction.Down));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool FillPoint(int x, int y, int colorIndex)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= ActivePictureInfo.XCells ||
            y < 0 || y >= ActivePictureInfo.YCells ||
            ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] == -1 ||
            ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] == colorIndex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        ActivePictureInfo.ColorNumbers[y][x] = colorIndex;
        return true;
    }

    private struct PointDirection
    {
        public PointDirection(int x, int y, Direction direction)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Direction = direction;
        }

        public int X { get; }
        public int Y { get; }
        public Direction Direction { get; }
    }

    private enum Direction : byte
    {
        Up,
        Right,
        Down,
        Left
    }
```